# Cannot write in the Docker Quickstart Terminal

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a container for a Django App, which uses MySQL-Server. The problem is, when I build the image it will install MySQL-Server which prompts me for setting a password, sadly I cannot write.

I am running this on Windows, so I am using the docker-toolbox and writing in the Docker Quickstart Terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137483/how-to-run-command-during-docker-build-which-requires-a-tty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no tty access during docker build. It is assumed that anything requiring tty would be run after running container.

In cases like yours you can try `RUN echo 'pswd'` or reading from a local file. Neither is recommended due to exposure of password.

Comment: Run echo 'password' is a possible solution, however, if I add it in my Dockerfile prior to installing mysql-server its too early and if I add it after installing the server its too late :S. Am I not seeing something here :S ?

Comment: Add it on same RUN command as installing MySQL: `RUN echo 'pswd' | <your_install_my_sql_command>`

Comment: Yet it stops again at **New password for the MySQL "root" user:** even when I have `RUN echo 'pswd' | apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-server` in my Dockerfile

Comment: You need to run it on the install command: `RUN apt-get update && echo 'pswd' | apt-get install -y mysql-server`

Comment: I copied your suggestion and it still stops at **New password for the MySQL "root" user:**

Comment: Then use [debconf](https://serversforhackers.com/video/installing-mysql-with-debconf) and try (change the versions):

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y debconf-utils && sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password password your_password' && 
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server/root_password_again password your_password' &&
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server-5.6`

Comment: After trying it, I get **/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected**

Comment: Default Ubuntu shell is dash. Run above with /bin/bash -c before it

Comment: I think :
`RUN echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password 1234" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password 1234" | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-server`
Solved the issue, yet I am still having an issue with the socket.

Comment: **django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")** This is the error I get after running the image.

Comment: That's perhaps a different question :-). Google it there are answers for it

Comment: I just noticed that while building I get the following text in red: 

**debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog

debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)

debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline

debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline

debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)

debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype

dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:** At this moment, I am not sure whether mysql-server was installed properly.

Comment: The debconf link mentioned above should help you set it up.